# Проблема с фоновым видео на сайте на Django

Tags: django, видео, iphone, safari

Перенес сайт, написанный на Django, с YandexCloud на GoogleCloud.
На YandexCloud фоновое видео:

```
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop> 
        <source src="http://ip-адрес/static/img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://ip-адрес/static/img/video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://ip-адрес/static/img/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

проигрывалось во всех браузерах, кроме Safari в macOS и кроме всех браузеров на iPhone.
После переноса на новый сервер фоновое видео перестало проигрываться везде.
В чем причины того, что оно не проигрывалось в Safari и на iPhone раньше и перестало проигрываться везде теперь, не понятно.

Comment: Ну а хотя бы по прямой ссылке видео открывается?

Comment: Да, оно же находится в папке static проекта Django, которая открыта для чтения извне.

Comment: А сам сайт на том же адресе `http://ip-адрес/` расположен?

Comment: Блин, ip видео не поменял на новый ip (нового сервера), хотя и старый ip доступен. Сейчас проверю.